# How to use result set of executeQuery() of one method to different methods

Tags: java, jdbc

I have one method called ExecuteQuery which is responsible for executing the query.
It is defined as :

```
public int ExecuteQuery(String itemCode) {
ps = jdbcConnection.prepareStatement(SomeQuery);
rs = ps.executeQuery();
}
```

I have three different methods in which I want to use the same result set. Obviosuly, I do not want to execute the same query thrice since it hampers my time complexity.

```
 private Map<String, ItemRelation> loadItemRelations(String itemCode) throws PosfException {
        Map<String, ItemRelation> relations = new LinkedHashMap<String, ItemRelation>();

        try {

             **while (rs.next()) {**
```

How can I use **rs** in this function so that it loops with the result which I got while executing rs=ps.executeQuery();

I have three functions which need same query results to perform different actions.

Comment: Leaving the connection open across method calls (and time) might not be a good idea.  Could you cache the result in your Java code somewhere?  Otherwise, you can just run the query three times when it is appropriate to do it.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Obviously I want to do caching too.. In fact that will be my next question once I get the answer to this question. I have to do caching so that I can close the connection immediately.

Comment: One simple to implement a cache in Java is to create a singleton class which will hold the data.  Good on you for closing the connection immediately.

Comment: In the while loop you can't call func1, func2, func3 and pass them the iteration result?

Comment: @apadenin I have three functions which do different actions.. The actions contained in this while loop are different for different functions. I have to create one while loop finside three different functions. private Map<String, ItemRelation> loadItemRelations(String itemCode) throws PosfException {
        Map<String, ItemRelation> relations = new LinkedHashMap<String, ItemRelation>();
 is a function difinition

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Thanks a lot, Can you also help in using this rs variable?

Answer (score 1):

You have two options:

1. Normally, a ResultSet is [`TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY). Change that to [`TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE) (or [`TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE)) by specifying that option on the [`prepareStatement()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#prepareStatement%28java.lang.String,%20int,%20int%29) call. That way you can call [`beforeFirst()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#beforeFirst%28%29) to reset the ResultSet to the beginning and iterate it again.
2. Load all the rows from the `ResulSet` into memory, e.g. as a `List<MyRowClass>`. Then you can iterate that list as many times as needed, and isolate the JDBC calls to a single place. Advantage: Column values are typed, and things like handling of nulls for primitives ([`wasNull()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html)) only needs to be done in one place.

I'd suggest going with option 2.

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution.
First you need to save the result to other type (like TableModel) and then you data in TableModel. Like Datatable in C#.
This my class. Hope to help you

```
    package saoviet.amisystem.model.datacollection;
    import java.sql.ResultSet;
    import java.sql.ResultSetMetaData;
    import java.sql.SQLException;
    import java.util.Vector;
    import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
    import javax.swing.table.TableModel;



public class DataTable {

    public TableModel dataTable;

    public TableModel getDataTable() {
        return dataTable;
    }

    private Vector<String> columnNames;
    private Vector<Vector<Object>> rows = new Vector<Vector<Object>>();

    private TableModel resultSetToTableModel(ResultSet rs) {
        try {

            ResultSetMetaData metaData = rs.getMetaData();
            int numberOfColumns = metaData.getColumnCount();

            // Get the column names
            for (int column = 0; column < numberOfColumns; column++) {
                this.columnNames.addElement(metaData.getColumnLabel(column + 1));
            }

            // Get all rows.
            while (rs.next()) {
                Vector<Object> newRow = new Vector<Object>();
                for (int i = 1; i <= numberOfColumns; i++) {
                    newRow.addElement(rs.getObject(i));
                }

                this.rows.addElement(newRow);
            }

            return new DefaultTableModel(rows, this.columnNames);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }

    public DataTable() {
    }

    public DataTable(ResultSet result) throws SQLException {
        this.columnNames = new Vector<String>();
        this.dataTable = this.resultSetToTableModel(result);
    }

    public String getValue(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
        return this.dataTable.getValueAt(rowIndex, columnIndex).toString();
    }

    public String getValue(int rowIndex, String columnName) {
        return this.getValue(rowIndex, this.columnNames.indexOf(columnName));
    }

    public void addRow(Object[] obj) {

        Vector<Object> newRow = new Vector<Object>();

        String columIndex = "";
        if (this.columnNames == null) {
            this.columnNames = new Vector<String>();
            for (int i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
                columIndex = "" + i;
                this.columnNames.addElement(columIndex);
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
            newRow.addElement(obj[i]);
        }

        this.rows.addElement(newRow);
        this.dataTable = new DefaultTableModel(rows, this.columnNames);
    }

    public int rowCount() {
        return this.rows.size();
    }
}
```